# Final Price including tax in magento

Tags: php, magento

Hi I am trying to get details of all items in the current order in Magento.
All values are ok.But here AMT has value without tax. How can I get         value including tax?

```
function getOrderProductsList($order) {
        $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
        $purchasedSkus = array();
        $count_orderItems = count($orderItems);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count_orderItems; $i++) {
            $purchasedSkus[$i] = array(
              'ITEM' => $orderItems[$i]['sku'],
                'QTY' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['qty_ordered'],0), // no decimals
                'AMT' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['price'],2), // 2 decimal places
                'DCNT' => number_format(abs($orderItems[$i]['discount_amount']),2) 
            );
        }
        return $purchasedSkus;
    }
```